# iTunes/Music standard music organization? & how to repair?

Tags: itunes, music

I don't know whether Apple changed the design, but I find that I have directories of both
`…/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/(artist)` and `…/iTunes/iTunes Media/(artist)`

Many albums have a subset of their songs with "original file cannot be found" and if I "would like to locate it," I can find it in whichever of those two paths doesn't match where the Music app thinks it should be.  But some of the ones that **are** usable are duplicated in the other directory.

What could cause this, and what would be the simplest way to fix it?

I **do** have the preferences set to copy imports and keep organized.

Comment: Since when does this happen? Did you upgrade your Mac, migrate your Music Library, restore from backup or similar?

Comment: First _discovered_ today on a two-week-old MBP.  No idea how long ago it happened or how.  Anything in /Users (which includes the music library) was migrated with Migration Assistant from TM backups which came from the old MBP.  Both MBPs were on the last version of Catalina.  Old one had been in use for years.  New one was upgraded to Big Sur _after_ the migration.  NO changes to the library or its preferences have been done on the new machine (at least not by me).